# React Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined in if-block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, webstorm, setstate

I am creating my first ReactJS front-end application and am running into a problem. When I try to call my setState function (or any other function for that matter) with this. before it inside an if block, I get the error.

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of
> undefined

When I call the functions inside my didComponentMount() everything is fine so I think the problem is the if block. I have tried several solutions on different questions but none have an if block so it doesn't work for me.

Function that throws error:

```
getFilteredTrades() {
        if(document.getElementById("switch").checked){
            fetch("http://localhost:8080/trades/filter?plaform=NintendoSwitch").then(rse => rse.json()).then(
                result => {
                    this.setState({trades: result});
                }
            )
        } else if (document.getElementById("playstation").checked) {
            fetch("http://localhost:8080/trades/filter?platform=PlayStation").then(rse => rse.json()).then(
                result => {
                    this.setState({trades: result});
                }
            )
        } else if (document.getElementById("xbox").checked) {
            fetch("http://localhost:8080/trades/filter?platform=XBox").then(rse => rse.json()).then(
                result => {
                    this.setState({trades: result});
                }
            )
        } else if (document.getElementById("pc").checked) {
            fetch("http://localhost:8080/trades/filter?platform=PC").then(rse => rse.json()).then(
                result => {
                    this.setState({trades: result});
                }
            )
        } else {
            alert("No filter is selected, so all trades will be displayed.")
            this.getAllTrades();
        }
    }
```

Both setState, and getAllTrades will throw errors here.

getAllTrades():

```
getAllTrades() {
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/trades/all").then(rse => rse.json()).then(
            result => {
                this.setState({trades: result});
            }
        )
    }
```

constructor:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            trades: []
        }
    }
```

didComponentMount, where getAllTrades DOES WORK:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.getAllTrades();
    }
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `getFilteredTrades` and `getAllTrades` functions **`this` refers to the functions itself and not the object** and those functions don't have a member `setState`.

You can resolve the problem in two ways:

1. Declaring them as arrow functions which does not bind `this` by writing `getFilteredTrades = () => { ... }` and `getAllTrades = () => { ... }`.
2. Bind the `this` keyword of the functions to the class object by writing `this.getFilteredTrades = this.getFilteredTrades.bind(this)` and `this.getAllTrades = this.getAllTrades.bind(this)` in your constructor.

Comment: Both these solutions lead to a new error in my render function, saying that this.state.trades.map() is not a function.

Comment: Well, then you expect `this.state.trades` to be an array, but it is not. Check what you get from your `fetch` functions.

Comment: @Peter_Lehnhardt When I log it to my console, it does show an array as far as I'm concerned...

Comment: Can you call `console.log(this.state.trades, this.state.trades instanceof Array)` right before calling `this.state.trades.map( ... )`?

Comment: My bad, this was not the issue at all. I mistyped "platform" in the first fetch url and that's why it didn't return an array. Turns out your solution works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you're losing a context at some point. Try bind your methods or make them arrow functions:

```
getAllTrades=()=>{...}
```

If it doesn't help, try to combine it with self=this trick, which was suggested above